# Deploying Jenkins with docker in docker swarm

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm

So I am trying to run jenkins inside my docker swarm and I want it to be able to execute docker commands to build new docker images.

When I am running it locally with the docker-compose script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    build: ./jenkins
    image: munhunger/jenkins
    container_name: "jenkins"
    ports:
      - "81:8080"
    environment:
      - minio_url=<URL>
      - minio_access=<TOKEN>
      - minio_secret=<SECRET>
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/.jenkins/workspace:/root/.jenkins/workspace
      - /var/lib/jenkins:/var/lib/jenkins
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker
```

It works exactly as I want it to and it can build the following jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build war') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'gradle:latest' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'gradle war -b oven/build.gradle'
            }
        }
        stage('build dockerimage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir('oven') {
                        def image = docker.build("munhunger/highly-oven")

                        docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
                            image.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
                            image.push("latest")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem possible to deploy it to my docker swarm.
I am just constantly getting `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist`. This is when using Portainer to deploy it. Have I misconfigured something or what is going on?

EDIT:
I tested deploying the following compose file using `docker stack deploy -c jenkins.yml jenkins`

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: munhunger/jenkins
    container_name: "jenkins"
    ports:
      - "81:8080"
    environment:
      - minio_url=<URL>
      - minio_access=<ACCESS>
      - minio_secret=<SECRET>
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/.jenkins/workspace:/root/.jenkins/workspace
      - /var/lib/jenkins:/var/lib/jenkins
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker
```

But I am still getting `invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist`

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use bind-mounts or the docker socket to use Jenkins inside a docker container. It's fine to use named volumes to store your important (persistant) config data, but you can build images with the docker command without needing to use the host docker socket.

See https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/

and https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ (docker in docker)

and http://vfarcic.github.io/jenkins-swarm/#/cover

Answer (score 2):

You need to use, docker compose `version: '3'or greater` to deploy services to swarm. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

Use `docker stack deploy` to deploy the compose file - 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

Compose ref - 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

FYI - docker compose v3 doesn't support `build`, you need to feed images to the swarm in order to deploy it.

Comment: I tried all that(se my edit) but I still get the same result

Comment: Have a look at docker event logs and see what source volume directory it is complaining for.